# How to apply different image styles to the same image used on main html page and pop up modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Update

Based on the below answer, I have changed the code to this which seems to work, althought I'm not sure its really best pratice coding.

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');

                    $('.go').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
                    $('.go img').removeClass('BadgeImgOutline');    


                        // It was $this but its been changed to target the complete parent object to get all info into the modal box/////
                    $(this).parent().appendTo('#badgeselect');
                   $(this).addClass('BadgeImgOutlineSmall'); 
                   $('.go img').addClass('BadgeImgOutline');
```

I have an image inside a underscore wrapper that has a class BadgeImgOutline associated to it. This class displays the image at 100% width and height. Which is what I want.

```
wrapper.append('<img class="images BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
```

The following code then takes all elements inside the wrapper (inc the image) and adds it to a modal pop up box.

Instead of showing the image at 100% here, I only want to show it at 50%, but the original BadgeImgOutline css is still being applied. If I change it, it will change it for the main html page as well as the pop up.

How do I get around this? can I remove the css styling for the image before it gets added to the pop up window, or add another css atyle after it has been added to the pop up?

```
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                        $('.go').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
                            // It was $this but its been changed to target the complete parent object to get all info into the modal box/////
                        $(this).parent().appendTo('#badgeselect');




            $('#modal').reveal({
```

Comment: Add a secondary class to the image displayed in the popup and override the width.

Comment: @MelanciaUK you mean add this?  document.getElementById("img").className += " MyClass"; if you can give an example I will accept answer

Comment: If the solution in the answer doesn't work, please add the markup to the question so I can tweak it to fit. But I'm sure you'll get the idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the `width` in some ways. I would just add a secondary `class` to this particular element:

You could re-use this bit:

```
$('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

And replace with:

```
$('.go img').addClass('popupImg');
```

On your styles, just add the new rule (observing that it should come after the default rule):

```
.go img.popupImg {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: see my updated question, I too what you provided and played around to get it to work, not 100% sure my methods are best practice but it works. Do you want to update the answer or for me to accept as is?

Comment: I just didn't get why did you remove the class `BadgeImgOutline` to re-add it later on again `BadgeImgOutline`. But your method is OK.